# Bash script to find files in folders

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have a couple of folders as

```
Main/  
   /a  
   /b  
   /c    
 ..
```

I have to pass input file `abc1.txt`, `abc2.txt` from each of these folders respectively as an input file to my python program.
The script right now is,

```
for i in `cat file.list`
do
echo $i
cd $i
#works on the assumption that there is only one .txt file
inputfile=`ls | grep .txt`
echo $inputfile
python2.7 ../getDOC.py $inputfile
sleep 10
cd ..
done
echo "Script executed successfully"
```

So I want the script to work correctly regardless of number of .txt files.

Can anyone let me know if there is any inbuilt command in shell to fetch the correct .txt files in case for multiple .txt files?

Comment: What is the relation between your file `file.list` and the `.txt` files? When is your `$i` variable used apart from the `echo $i` line?

Comment: What is unique in your .txt file that has to be passed to the pyhton script? if its the name of the file cant you just do find . -name file.txt

Comment: file.list has all the folders in it. The .txt file is in all the folders. And the $i variable is used to cd into that folder, somehow It got omitted out in the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `find` command is well suited for this with `-exec`:

```
find /path/to/Main -type f -name "*.txt" -exec python2.7 ../getDOC.py {} \; -exec sleep 10 \;
```

**Explanation:**

- `find` - invoke `find`
- `/path/to/Main` - The directory to start your search at. By default `find` searches recursively.
- `-type f` - Only consider files (as opposed to directories, etc)
- `-name "*.txt"` - Only find the files with `.txt` extension. This is quoted so bash doesn't auto-expand the wildcard `*` via globbing.
- `-exec ... \;` - For each such result found, run the following command on it:
- `python2.7 ../getDOC.py {};` - the `{}` part is where the search result from the `find` gets substituted into each time.
- `sleep 10` - sleep for 10 seconds after each time python script is run on the file. Remove this if you don't want it to sleep.

Comment: I doubt you tried your solution: it fails miserably because the first semicolon is used by bash. You probably mean `find /path/to/Main -type f -name "*.txt" -exec python2.7 ../getDOC.py {} \; -exec sleep 10 \;`

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf oh durr, just woke up; fixing.

Comment: That's better, you now deserve you +1 `;-)`.

Answer (score 1):

Better using [globs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) :

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
for i in Main/**/*txt; do
    python2.7 ../getDOC.py "$i"
    sleep 10
done
```

This example is recursive and require [bash4](/questions/tagged/bash4)

Comment: That's my favorite way of doing (for such simple search patterns). It would just be perfect with a `shopt -s nullglob` or a `shopt -s failglob`.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name *.txt | xargs python2.7 ../getDOC.py
```

Comment: `*.txt` won't be expanded.. quotes needed.

Comment: I would add the `-print0` and `-type f` to find and `-0` option to xargs as well.

Comment: I would just not use this method at all, and use the `-exec` option from find, as sampson-chen (nearly) did.